# Best way to serialize a Float in java to be read by C++ app?

Tags: java, c++, serialization

I need to serialize a java Float to be read by an application written in C++ over Socket comms. Is there a standard for this? It would be easiest to use the method floatToIntBits in the Float Class, however I am not sure how standard that is.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That is, in fact, pretty standard. The `floatToIntBits` function gives you the actual bytes of the IEEE encoding of the float.  The only problem is that the bytes will be big-endian, so you'll have to reverse the byte order when reading into your C++ application. (unless your C++ platform is also big-endian!)

Comment: The standard is IEEE 754... also, big endian is also known as "network byte order" and is the endianness usually used for binary data over the wire.

Answer (score 6):

Use [`Float.floatToIntBits()`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Float.html#floatToIntBits(float)) (or `Float.floatToRawIntBits()` if you want to preserve NaN values) to convert the float to an integer.  `floatToIntBits()` is specified to return the integer in IEEE 754 format, which is the format used by virtually all C/C++ implementations.  You should then convert the integer into a byte array in network byte order (big-endian), which you can then safely serialize to a file, socket, byte stream, etc.:

```
int floatBits = Float.floatToIntBits(myFloat);
byte floatBytes[] = new byte[4];
floatBytes[0] = (byte)(floatBits >> 24);
floatBytes[1] = (byte)(floatBits >> 16);
floatBytes[2] = (byte)(floatBits >> 8);
floatBytes[3] = (byte)(floatBits);
```

Comment: are you sure that this is correct? I think you need the >>> shift instead of >>

Comment: @martinus: It makes no difference in this case.  Since the cast to `byte` only looks at the bottom 8 bits, the values that get shifted into the top 8-24 bits (0's in the case of `>>`, or copies of the sign bit in the case of `>>>`) don't matter.

Comment: ah, now I finally understand what this >>> does :)

Answer (score 0):

Unless you really really need it to be binary, either for bandwidth or speed reasons, personally I'd just convert it to a string.  It avoids all sorts of binary compatibility problems.

Comment: ...then, wouldn't this introduce problems of string encoding (Unicode/Ansi/etc)?

Comment: Numbers are pretty standard across encodings.

Comment: Another reason beyond compactness is performance -- there are multiple orders of magnitude difference between accurate string-to-double (and vice versa) conversion that Java does, and straight-forward appending of bytes.

Comment: @StaxMan, what part of "or speed reasons" are you disagreeing with?

Comment: I don't disagree with comment itself -- I agree, those are 2 reasons to use, and if they don't matter, no need to use binary -- but just wanted to mention that difference can be very significant, more so than with most other data types.

For example, converting ints to/from String is not all that slow (relatively speaking). Likewise, bandwidth difference is not as clearly favoring binary format as performance.