# Convert Java floats to C

Tags: java, c, floating-point

I have a java program using objects containing huge arrays of floats. 
Thing is for optimization reasons, I need to convert part of this code into C.

For benchmarking, I already converted the desired method in C. 
Thing is instead of taking objects as inputs, it now takes those float arrays.

I saved those arrays in files in Java, in order to easily access it from my C code. 
Problem is, Java floats and C floats are apparently completely different, and I get dummy values in my C code.

I did not find any source on the internet that could help me in this task. 
[I did find this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1258097/best-way-to-serialize-a-float-in-java-to-be-read-by-c-app), but it is for C++ and I don't have access to those classes.

Would you have any suggestions? 
I could develop some kind of converter I guess, but It may take some time and there is probably a better solution online.

Thx,

EDIT :

I am saving the float array using a DataOutputStream and its writeFloat method.

Comment: Why don't you just use JNI/JNA to interface Java and C? That way you don't have to deal with files...

Comment: How are you storing you array of float in the file ? are you using ObjectOutputStream or writing java objects directly to file ?

Comment: @nneonneo : I simplified to avoid giving useless information, but the actual C code will later by run on GPU so I am not sure I can do that :s.

Comment: You can still use JNI even if you run on the GPU. You just pass the floats from Java to C through JNI, and from C to the GPU through e.g. CUDA.

Comment: @nneonneo I was actually looking at it .Thx :)

Comment: @jlengrand, I would suggest that when you store the array data in file, use simple textual representation (convert array element to string) and then when you read them in C, convert back from Strings to float arrays.

Comment: @Santosh As the objective here is performance, that is a really bad idea.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would use JavaCL or JavaCV to use the GPU directly.

Note: these libraries work with Intel/AMD CPUs as well so you don't need to use the GPU if its not faster.

BTW: float in Java and C is the same.  However if you use ObejctOutputStream this can only be read by Java and if you use DataOutputStream the data will be in Big Endian format. If you have an Intel/AMD CPU which is little endian you have to swap the bytes around.

If you use ByteBuffer and NIO to write the data you can make it big endian or little endian.  The later requires no translation.

Note: you can access a `float[]` or `FloatBuffer` via JNI meaning it doesn't need to be written to a file.

To use FloatBuffer I suggest

```
FloatBuffer fb = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(size*4)
                           .order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder())
                           .asFloatBuffer();
```

Comment: I knew I shouldn't mention GPUs ;). I already have functional Java/CUDA code with JCuda. We know want to optimize our kernel, and need the various tools of Visual Studio for that. I am creating a simple C code so that I can use the NSight tools

Comment: In that case, the simplest solution is to access the `float[]` from JNI. If you have to export a file to a different program, you can use `FloatBuffer` with `.order(ByteOrder.LITTLE_ENDIAN);` to write the data is the byte order C will expect on most systems.

Comment: For simplicity of Unit Testing and because of the nesting of my objects I decided to go for FloatBuffer. Thx a lot though, it made me aware of JNI at the same time !

Comment: @jlengrand Added a suggestion on how to construct the Float buffer. Note: The address() is the start of the native memory where the floats are stored.

Comment: Yep, this is exactly how I do it :). I also prepend the size of the table (as they are 2 to 3 d). Thx for helping future readers ;)

Comment: BTW If you are using OpenJDK/HotSpot JVM, you can use `((DirectBuffer) fb).cleaner().clean()` to free the native portion deterministically.

Comment: There is no single C `float` type, and the questioner did not specify a particular implementation. Most implementations use IEEE-754, but not all. Answers should not advise readers that Java and C use the same floating-point type without this caution, in case somebody is working on an old system, a special embedded platform, or other unusual implementations.

Comment: @EricPostpischil Does this apply to the CUDA flavour of C?

Comment: @PeterLawrey: Although CUDA is mentioned in comments, it is not part of the question or the answer until it is edited into them. Recall that StackOverflow is not merely a forum for individual problem solving but creates a record of questions and answers to be used as reference by later visitors. The answer should match the stated question or should at least state the assumptions it makes.

Answer (score 3):

First, you can run Java programs on GPU without converting to C: [project RootBeer](https://github.com/pcpratts/rootbeer1).

Second, Java floats are the same as C floats. The trick is to write and read them correctly. I recommend to use  [FileChannel](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/nio/channels/FileChannel.html) and [ByteBuffer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/nio/ByteBuffer.html) which have methods to read and write floats. Pay attention to byte order, ByteBuffer have methods to set desired order.