# java read a byte stream of float number

Tags: java, io

Not familiar with java IO. Here is the question: a byte stream which contains a series of float number between -1 and 1. How should I read the input?

I've tried this:

```
BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(new ByteInputStream(buf, length));
```

but get no idea.

Thanks.

Comment: Are the numbers stored in textual representation (i.e. 0.24354) or in binary? Which number format is used?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could read a float from a buffer like this:

```
try(DataInputStream dis = new DataInputStream(new ByteArrayInputStream(buf, 0, len))){
    // ...
    float v = dis.readFloat();
    // ...
}
```

`BufferedReader` is not needed as this one would read from a buffer.

If your floats are coming from i.e. C++ application, you could read integers and use `Float.intBitsToFloat()` to convert them to Java floats: [Best way to serialize a Float in java to be read by C++ app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1258097/best-way-to-serialize-a-float-in-java-to-be-read-by-c-app)

Comment: Thank you. And what if the input is from socket client, is this ok ?try(DataInputStream dis = new DataInputStream(socket.getInputStream())){
    // ...
    float v = dis.readFloat();
    // ...
}