# Using BufferedOutputStream in Java

Tags: java

Recently, I've been learning about File I/O in java, and I came to know that Buffered Streams make the whole process more efficient, by storing the data intermittently and only writing to the disk(or reading from it) when the buffer is full.

Now, I have a program where I have an `ArrayList` of 256 `boolean`, and a floating point value.
I am trying to serialize this data(I do not wish to simply write the data in human-readable form).
So what I do currently is have a `FileOutputStream` chained to an `ObjectOutputStream` and use its `writeObject()` method to first write the `boolean` array, and then the `float` variable. I do likewise when reading using `FileInputStream` and `ObjectInputStream`.

Now, since I'm curious how I would go about using the `BufferedOutputStream` in here, I went through the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/BufferedOutputStream.html) but the two overloaded write methods it has don't seem flexible enough to me-

1. The first, which takes a byte array and a couple more parameters for offset and length
2. The second, which takes a byte.

So, would that mean I have to convert my `boolean` array to a byte array to be able to use the `BufferedOutputStream` object? How then would I convert my float to a byte? I'm also confused on how I would read in the data with `BufferedInputStream`.
And would it be worth using Buffers here after all the conversion that's taking place?

Here's my original code without the buffers

```
public class MySaveListener implements ActionListener { //this is an inner class by the way
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ev) {
            JFileChooser fileSave = new JFileChooser();
            fileSave.showSaveDialog(theFrame);
            saveFile(fileSave.getSelectedFile());
        }
    }

private void saveFile(File file){
        boolean[] checkboxState = new boolean[256];

        for(int i = 0; i < 256; i++){
            JCheckBox check = (JCheckBox) checkboxList.get(i);
            if (check.isSelected()){
                checkboxState[i] = true;
            }
        }

        try{
            FileOutputStream fileStream = new FileOutputStream(file);
            ObjectOutputStream os = new ObjectOutputStream(fileStream);
            os.writeObject(checkboxState);
            os.writeObject(1239.87f);
            os.close();
        } catch(Exception ex){ex.printStackTrace();}
    }

public class MyLoadListener implements ActionListener {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ev) {
            JFileChooser fileOpen = new JFileChooser();
            fileOpen.showOpenDialog(theFrame);
            loadFile(fileOpen.getSelectedFile());
        }
    }

private void loadFile(File file){
        boolean[] checkboxState = null;
        try{
            FileInputStream fileIn = new FileInputStream(file);
            ObjectInputStream is = new ObjectInputStream(fileIn);
            checkboxState = (boolean[]) is.readObject();
            float loadTempo = (float)is.readObject();
            is.close();
        } catch(Exception ex){ex.printStackTrace();}

        for(int i = 0; i < 256; i++){
            JCheckBox check = (JCheckBox) checkboxList.get(i);
            if (checkboxState[i]){
                check.setSelected(true);
            }
            else{
                check.setSelected(false);
            }
        }
    }
```

So, what changes would I have to bring in here to make use of `BufferedOutputStream` and `BufferedInputStream` ?

Comment: Yes, what I have now works. However, I'm looking to make it better. Also could you elaborate how I could use booleans too, since the signature of the method only allows for byte arrays?

Comment: Do NOT look at DataOutputStream. This is a Java-only transmission protocol that is now decades from relevance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your understanding of Buffering is not correct. Stream and Writer/Reader buffers are useful if you are doing *inefficient writing/reading*, such as reading and processing line by line, rather than just trying to read from a stream as fast as you can. On the writing side, it means sending the complete message in 1 call, rather than making several write calls before sending the data. If you are doing *efficient* reading and writing, you don't need a buffer.

As to the question of how to serialize: The Object streams are easy to use, but end up leaving you with incompatible data eventually. If you want your serialization to be optimal, I'd advise you to convert the boolean[] to a byte[] which you can be written through a regular OutputStream

Comment: and how would I store the float variable with BufferedOutputStream? Wouldn't converting it to byte cause loss of data?

Comment: @Ayush https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1258097/best-way-to-serialize-a-float-in-java-to-be-read-by-c-app